# Zend Framework - Class Inheritance with Module Prefix

Tags: php, zend-framework

I'm implementing some code with PHP and Zend Framework and working with modules.
I set in my `application.ini` the following line:

```
resources.frontController.prefixDefaultModule = "true"
```

So my controller classes in `admin` module are named like `Admin_{class name}`

Now, I'm trying to use some inheritance like

```
class Admin_IndexController extends Admin_BaseController
```

But I always get the same error message:

```
Warning: include_once(BaseController.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\xampp\php\pear\Zend\Loader.php on line 146

Warning: include_once(): Failed opening 'BaseController.php' for inclusion (include_path='.;\xampp\php\PEAR;..\library;..\library\Carrinho;..\application;..\application\models;..\application\modules;..\application\plugins') in C:\xampp\php\pear\Zend\Loader.php on line 146

Fatal error: Class 'BaseController' not found in C:\xampp\htdocs\SiteSermap\application\modules\admin\controllers\IndexController.php on line 3
```

Obs.: I've already tried using this (without "Admin" prefix)

```
class Admin_IndexController extends BaseController
```

**Does anyone know how to solve this?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using the auto loader module, the name of the file tells Zend where the file is located in your file tree. In your case, you have to place your file in the Admin directory. Like this:

```
modules/admin/BaseController.php => Admin_BaseController.php
modules/somemodule/submodule/SomeController.php => Somemodule_Submodule_SomeController.php
```

Is your base class in the right folder?

Note: the Admin_IndexController does not need the Admin_ prefix unless it's being included from somewhere else (which would be a bad practice). This is why Zend does find your IndexController class and not your BaseController one.